# How to handle comma in data in pipe delimited file in Pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark, airflow, delimiter

Sample data present at raw_file_path

```
member_id|member_name|member_birthdate
1|Rooney ,Shannon|16180705 
2|Alea ,Fitzpatrick|16990120 
3|Daquan ,Cooper|16681214 

csvData = spark.read.option("delimiter",delim).format("csv")\ 
    .load(raw_file_path,header='true',inferSchema='true').show()
```

I want output as pipe delmiter , but as 1 comma is their in the value so I am not getting expected results

Result I am getting :

```
|           member_id|member_name|member_birthdate|
+--------------------+-----------+----------------+
|1|Rooney ,Shannon...|       null|            null|
|2|Alea ,Fitzpatri...|       null|            null|
|3|Daquan ,Cooper|...|       null|            null|
```

Expected result

```
|member_id|   member_name|member_birthdate|
|1  | Rooney ,Shannon|        16180705|
|2  | Alea ,Fitzpatri|        16990120|
|3  | Daquan ,Cooper |        16681214|
```

Comment: Can you try `csvData = spark.read.csv(raw_file_path, header=True, sep='|').show()`?

Comment: its still showing same result